# How can I do an action before another in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my webpage I wrote this:

https://jsfiddle.net/qnztbucg/

HTML:

```
<div id="faketxt" contenteditable>Write Here</div>
    <button id='btn'>OK</button>
<div id='casella'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#faketxt {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: 28px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
}

#casella{
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    font-size: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("body").on("click", "#btn", function(){
    var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
    var secondo = document.getElementById('casella');
    secondo.innerHTML=primo.innerHTML;
});

function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
    var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';

    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
    link.click(); 
}

var fileName =  'ciao.txt';

$('#btn').click(function(){
    downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'casella','text/html');
});
```

It works all perfectly, but when it starts the download of the div#casella the file downloaded is empty. The reason why I think is that the page downloads the div before the text is in it...

How can I make the text in the second div before it starts the download?
I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *three* listeners (including the `onclick` function) for `#btn` that will run *asynchronously* - copy the text to the div *before* downloading - see demo below:

```js
function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
  var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';

  link.setAttribute('download', filename);
  link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
  link.click();
}

var fileName = 'ciao.txt';

$('#btn').click(function() {
  var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
  var secondo = document.getElementById('casella');
  secondo.innerHTML = primo.innerHTML;
  downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'casella', 'text/html');
});
```

```css
#faketxt {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font: medium -moz-fixed;
  font: -webkit-small-control;
  height: 28px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  resize: both;
  width: 400px;
}
#casella {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="faketxt" contenteditable>Write Here</div>
<button id='btn'>OK</button>

<button class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand('italic',false,null);" title="Italicize Highlighted Text"><i>I</i>
</button>
<button class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand( 'bold',false,null);" title="Bold Highlighted Text"><b>B</b>
</button>
<button class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand( 'underline',false,null);"><u>U</u>
</button>
<button class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand( 'fontSize',false,5);">S
</button>
<button class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand( 'foreColor',false,'#ff0000');">R
</button>

<div id='casella'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are binding 2 handlers with the click event on your #btn that is why empty file is getting downloaded since both handler will execute asynchronously.

you should just bind one and at the one of first where you are copying the innerHTML and after that call the download function

```
$("body").on("click", "#btn", function() {
  var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
  var secondo = document.getElementById('casella');
  secondo.innerHTML = primo.innerHTML;
  downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'casella', 'text/html');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5e8dzq2h/

Answer (score 0):

You use innerhtml of wrong element:

```
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
```

but, you must use primo.innerHtml, like this:

```
var elHtml = primo.innerHtml;
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
```

I'm edited your fiddle, this is solution: https://jsfiddle.net/qnztbucg/3/

Answer (score 0):

That's happened because the first handler (`$("body").on("click", "#btn", ...`) is called in a second time.

So why ?

Because this handler is attached to body element and it will be triggered when body received event, so after `$('#btn').click()` has triggered.

To avoid this problem use `$('#btn').click()` instead of `on` synthax.

Fixed version : https://jsfiddle.net/qnztbucg/2/